# <img> dentro de div não aparece quando utilizado canvas2image

Tags: canvas, img, html2canvas, html5-canvas

Estou usando um script para salvar uma div em png.
Dentro dessa div tem um , porém essa imagem não aparece no resultado final,após salvar.
O código que estou utilizando é esse

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($(".container-assinatura"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            //Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);

         }

      });
   });
});
```

Lembrando que esse script não funciona no Chrome,somente no Mozilla,e aqui na empresa onde trabalho,para qual estou desenvolvendo isso,95% das pessoas utilizam Chrome.
Edit: O HTML do meu código é esse

```
<div style="color:#000" class="container-assinatura">
                <div id="gerador">
                        <p style="margin-bottom: 0in"></p>
                        <table class="MsoNormalTable" style="border-collapse:collapse" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="height:84.8pt">
                                  <td style="width:154.25pt;border:none;border-right:solid #E36C0A 2.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:84.8pt" valign="top" width="206">
                                        <p class="MsoNormal">
                                            <span style="font-size:16.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="MsoNormal">
                                            <div id="logo_position">
                                                <img id="logo_filial" src="png/marca_laranja.png">
                                                <span
                                                style="font-size:9.0pt"><o:p></o:p>
                                                </span>

                                            </div>
                                        </p>
                                  </td>
                                  <td style="width:205.55pt;border:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:84.8pt" valign="top" width="274">
                                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                                        <b>
                                            <span style="color:#E36C0A"><b>{{nome}}</b></span>                                      
                                        </b>

                                        <b>
                                            <span style="font-size:9.0pt;color:red"></span><br>
                                        </b>

                                        <b>
                                            <span style="font-size:9.0pt;color:gray">{{setor}}<i><br></i></span>
                                        </b>

                                        <span style="font-size:9.0pt;color:gray"><o:p></o:p></span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                                        <span style="font-size:9.0pt;color:black"><b>Tel:</b> {{telefone}}<br><b>E-mail:</b> </span>
                                        <span style="font-size:9.0pt">
                                            <a href="mailto:{{email}}">
                                                <span style="color:blue">{{email}}</span>
                                            </a>
                                            <br><span><b>Rocket.Chat:</b> {{rocket}}</span>
                                            <span style="font-size:9.0pt"><o:p></o:p></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                        <p style="margin-bottom: -72px"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p><font face="Ubuntu
                            Light"><font size="3"><br>
                            </font></font><br>
                        </p>
                        <div class="moz-signature"> </div>
                        <p style="margin-bottom: 0in"><br>
                        </p>
                        <div class="moz-signature"> </div>
                </div>           
            </div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-dark" value="Salvar Assinatura">
```

Comment: Estranho, pois eu utilizo e funciona no Chrome. Só com esse codigo fica dificil de ajudar, poste tambem seu `html`

Comment: Editei com o código da <div>

Comment: Uma duvida, na sua tela, a imagem é exibida (sem dar o `scroll`)?

Comment: Como assim dar o scrool? Você fala scrollar a tela para baixo?

Comment: Exatamente!!!!!

Comment: Sim,aparece normalmente,em ambos os monitores que eu uso,sendo que um deles é um pouco menor que o principal.

Comment: Você conseguiria reproduzir o erro em um `JSFiddle`?

Comment: A página toda em si é bem pequena,pois a <div> é uma assinatura de email. O projeto todo é de um gerador de assinatura,então não é nada muito extenso.

Comment: Então, por favor reproduza essa pagina no `JSFiddle` e ai conseguimos ver o suposto erro acontecendo e ajudar a resolver o problema.

Comment: Vou tentar usar o JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/FxHound/04t28hau/

Comment: O problema é basicamente o seguinte, ao apertar o botão Salvar Assinatura, aquela <div> branca é salva em .png, porém a logo(no caso a logo da AMD) não vem no resultado final em .png.

Comment: Não sei se tem algo a ver,mas a página não foi hospedada ainda..